# How to remove brackets, and count them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this: `(((foo)))`

I would like to get an object from the string like this: `{"text":"foo", "brackets" : 3}`

How is it possible?

Comment: Is your string always like this ? Then why not just count the '(' in the string by iterating over the chars ?

Comment: Unless you also need to validate the input string, such as checking whether the `)`s properly match with the `(`s, just count the `(`s at the start. Then, you can use that count to `substr` the inner portion out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't necessarily the best solution, but a regular expression to match multiple `(` with `(\(+)`, followed by everything up to `)` with `([^)]+)`, followed by multiple `)` with `(\)+)` is pretty easy.  This will allow you to validate that the parentheses are balanced before you build your object.

```
var s = '(((foo)))';
var parts = s.match(/^(\(+)([^)]+)(\)+)$/);
// ["(((foo)))", "(((", "foo", ")))"]

// If the start and end match, preventing something like `(((foo)` with unbalanced ()
// and the total length of the extracted array is 4
if (parts.length === 4 && parts[1].length === parts[3].length) {
  // Your result is:
  var yourResultObj = {
    "text": parts[2],
    "brackets": parts[1].length
  }
}
```

All of this can also be done with string maipulation, but the regex code may be clearer to read.

Comment: Perhaps change `\(+` to `\(*`, or at least include that as an alternative? This won't work if there are no parentheses. Still, +1!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have the same amount of opening parens as closing parens, you could do this to count them:

```
var myString = '(((foo)))';
var parens = (mainStr.split("(").length - 1); // 3
```

And to remove them:

```
var obj = {parens: parens, text: myString.substr(parens, myString.length - parens)};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that every opening brackets are counting, you could have a function like this one.

```
function makeStringObject(str) {
    var parts = str.split('(');
    return {
        'text': parts[parts.length-1].split(')')[0],
        'brackets': parts.length-1
    }
}
```